# How to calculate reletive weights (alpha) in Principal Component Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, matlab, machine-learning

I am trying to work through the method described in [this paper](http://trama.deib.polimi.it/allegati/Schutte_2000.pdf) of calculating a normalcy index using principal component analysis. I understand steps 1-5, except for the equation for eigenvectors which is $\mathbf e_i = \sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_j^ix_j$ where $\alpha_j^i$ are "relative weights determined solely by the orthonormality constraint." The matrix containing $\mathbf x_j$ is a 10x8 matrix but the eigenvectors ($\mathbf e_i$) are from the covariance matrix which is 8x8 (I did that part in MATLAB). Because there is a difference in matrix dimensions I can't divide $\mathbf e_i$ by $\mathbf x_j$ to find $\mathbf \alpha_j^i$. I need $\mathbf \alpha_j^i$ to complete the next steps (as far as I can tell) including mutiplying it by another 10x8 matrix $\mathbf z_j$. Please help me understand how I'm supposed to calculate $\mathbf \alpha_j^i$

Comment: it seems you just need to use the Gram-Schmidt process (check the Wikipedia entry for a start) to calculate the set of orthogonal vectors. I'm sure Matlab has a function that can do that for you.

Comment: The direct relationship between the original data matrix and the PCA of the covariance matrix is best done with SVD: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca/134283

Comment: @ChristiaanHattingh in regards to your first comment, the orthogonal (and normalised) vectors are the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix (ei). Did you suggest the Gram-Schmidt process because it will preserve the matrix dimensions (original matrix is 10x8, covariance is 8x8)?  I have a feeling not calculating the covariance matrix will defeat the purpose of PCA (although I'm not smart enough to know for sure).

Comment: no sorry it's been a while since I did PCA from scratch: there is a possibility that after eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix the eigenvectors are not orthogonal (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130882/why-are-principal-components-in-pca-eigenvectors-of-the-covariance-matrix-mutu) so then one would have to add a step to get an orthonormal basis (and hence I thought of Gram-Schmidt)...but this is really not the way to go...SVD is better. Maybe this can help: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1100.pdf (I haven't checked it in detail for correctness, but you can crossref)